# Oldest date from most recent set of records

Tags: mysql, date, range

How do I find the oldest date from the most recent set of records in MySQL?

Consider the below

```
+--------+-----------+------------+
| ID     | PRODUCTID | DATEACTIVE |
+--------+-----------+------------+
| 546502 | 23405     | 2017-07-20 |
| 545075 | 23405     | 2017-07-19 |
| 543651 | 23405     | 2017-07-18 |
| 456783 | 23405     | 2017-01-04 |
| 456782 | 23405     | 2017-01-03 |
| 456781 | 23405     | 2017-01-02 |
| 456780 | 23405     | 2017-01-01 |
| 65453  | 23405     | 2016-07-19 |
| 65452  | 23405     | 2016-07-18 |
+--------+-----------+------------+
```

I want to be able to find the most recent time a product was activated (18th July 2017)

Comment: Which is it? The oldest or most recent? You've asked for opposites.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: The oldest date in the recent set of concurrent dates.

Answer (score 1):

**Pls next time follow what Sloan said in the comments.**

If I understood your question, you could use something like this.
The query, in the inner part, "groups" the consecutive dates, giving a consecutive number for each "group".
Then select only the "first" group (the more recent) and numbers the rows in ascending order by date.
Finally, the row with the first "row number" is selected.

```
SELECT * 
 FROM (
         SELECT @rn:=@rn+1 AS RN,
             A.*
         FROM (
             SELECT @gr:= IF(@prev_date=DATE_ADD(dateactive, INTERVAL +1 DAY), @gr, @gr+1) AS GR
             ,TN.*
             ,@prev_date:=dateactive AS PD
            FROM TN
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT @gr:=0, @prev_date:=(SELECT MAX(dateactive) FROM TN)) R
            ORDER BY DATEACTIVE DESC 
             ) A
           CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn:=0) R2     
        WHERE GR=1     
        ORDER BY DATEACTIVE
      )B
WHERE RN=1;
```

Output:

```
RN  GR  id  productid   dateactive  PD
1   1   543651  23405   18.07.2017 00:00:00 2017-07-18
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(DATEACTIVE) as most_recent_time
FROM `YOUR_TABLE_NAME`
WHERE PRODUCTID = 'YOUR_ID'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ORDER BY` to sort the data by date, See code below:

```
SELECT *
FROM `YOUR_TABLE_NAME`
WHERE `PRODUCTID` = 'YOUR_ID' 
ORDER BY `DATEACTIVE` DESC;
```